# Unable to add service-based database in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I installed the Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 10 and then installed SQL Server 2012 successfully, I have connected to the server from Visual Studio but every time I try to add a service-based database to the windows form I'm creating, it says this

> Connection to SQL Server requires SQL server 2005 express or SQL
>   Server 2008 Express to be installed and running on the local
>   computer...

What should I do now?

[image: Error]

Comment: Did you try downloading the software at the link in the error message?

Comment: the link directs me to a page to download sql server which i already have installed on the system.